# Which approach is better :- having 2 classes in html tag or 2 classes with same property

Tags: html, css

Please help me determine which of the approach is better(having 2 classes in html tag or 2 classes with same property) and why?

**Approach 1**

```
<html><body>
     <p class="redColor buttonHeight"> button Red</p>
     <p class="blueColor buttonHeight"> button Blue</p>
    </body></html>

    .redColor{color:red}
    .blueColor{color:blue}
    .buttonHeight{height:10px}
```

**Approach 2**

```
<html><body>
 <p class="redColorHeight"> button Red</p>
 <p class="blueColorHeight"> button Blue</p>
</body></html>

.redColorHeight{color:red}
.blueColorHeight{color:blue}
.redColorHeight,.blueColorHeight{height:10px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try making your classes more general and give them names implying their purposes instead of their implementation, Such as `button-important` and `button-info`. Calling a CSS class in very specific name like `redButton` isn't really a good practice.

I believe this is a better practice:

```
 <p class="button button-important"> button Red</p>
 <p class="button button-info"> button Blue</p>

.button {
    height: 10px;
}
.button-important {
    color: red;
}
.button-info {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Itay, those are just hypothetical classnames, my actual question is about the css property implementation. Why is approach 1 better then approach 2 or vice versa

Comment: If you give your classes meaningful names, it will help you decide.  If there's a meaning for each class separately it may be advisable to separate them. If not, then the second way is okay.

Comment: @New_To_Android I suggest you refactor the sample in your question to be similar to this answer. It will help us responding :-)

Comment: I have refactored the sample.

Comment: @New_To_Android Please don't edit your original code out of the question - if you feel this is the proper solution (and the one you chose to go ahead with), mark Itay's answer as the accepted answer instead, so that future viewers will understand that's what happened.

Comment: @Itay You could probably condense this further by renaming `.button-important` and `.button-info` to just `.important` and `.info`. If it were necessary to specify an important or info button, one could just use a multiple-class selector. (ex. `.button.important`)

Comment: @Nightfirecat +1 You're correct

Answer (score 0):

It's all about which properties you want to extract as common. E.g. if all buttons in your app should be the same height, use an approach suggested by Itay. Place height def in style of button class. If it is not a case and you don't want to keep them exactly same height you can use the second approach.

Css gives us a classes and we shoul use them as a classes. I mean use them in similar way as classes in java. A class describes some common properties of objects. Here I see a button object. There is no color nor height object :-)

You can check for example twitter bootstrap framework. Just go to bootstrap page, open a DOM viewer in your favorite browser and analyse how there are particular "components" described by classes.